# Bad gateway (502) when using the Yammer REST API with ADAL

Tags: office365, yammer

Suddenly last Friday, we started getting `502 Bad Gateway nginx` responses when using the Yammer REST API.

The endpoint we use is:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/my_feed.json
```

Tokens are acquired using ADAL, where the Azure AD app has permissions to impersonate users.

Since we didn't make changes to our code and it affects multiple Azure AD applications, my suspicions are the following:

1. Something has broken in the Yammer API (the permission level is, after all, in preview)
2. There is some kind of throttling going on and our apps have been blocked.

My question is simply: if anyone else currently is experiencing the same issue, or if it is just us.

Comment: An AAD flow was previewed at one time, but I'm not aware that this is currently documented/supported. Are your calls successful with tokens obtained from the supported authorization flow from https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2?

Comment: Tokens are gained through AAD (using yammer as a resource) and worked properly up until last friday. It is likely that you are right though, that they have shut it down as it is not supported/documented. :(

Comment: We have reverted some changes that should provide you with some relief. I'm trying to clarify the future for this feature since it needs to be officially documented/supported to avoid situations like this one. In general, it is best to avoid the use of preview features in production code. IIRC some endpoints had issues with receiving these tokens so you are out of luck if an API didn't accept this token type. Yammer API tokens should work with all the endpoints.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! Thank you! Do you know if there are plans to take the yammer API out of preview, or are we strongly advice to look at the auth flow you sent in a previous post?

Comment: The recommended and fully supported method of using the API is to follow the OAuth flows that are documented on the developer.yammer.com site. This flow will work with all Yammer networks, including those which are not yet enforcing O365 identity. I think the consensus is that we'd like the Yammer API to operate just like any other O365 API and for this to get out of preview, but there is still some time to go before all networks are using O365 identity. The best thing for the community to do is to encourage network admins to enforce O365 identity.

Comment: @submarines - trying to accomplish the same thing. Are you passing the ADAL token in the headers as a bearer token? And is this still working for you?

Comment: Since the fix above we have had no issues.Yes we are including the token with every request, make sure you request a token for the resource yammer (and as Brian said above, this might not be fully supported)